# Getting `UnsupportedClassVersionError : Bad Version number in .class file` in Sun os 5.10 version

Tags: java, cron, sunos

I am using Sun os 5.10 version unix server and executing a bash script which is calling  a java class.
When I run that script manually the java class executes successfully .
But when I execute the same script using crontab job I am getting the below error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file`

I had compiled the java class with all Java versions starting from 1.8 to 1.4 but still i get that error.. the unix server has Java 1.6 version

Comment: How many versions of java do you have on your machine and how is cron calling it? I'd do a `which java` to see which one you're using when running manually and give the exact same path in the crontab

Comment: You should probably do `sudo -i which java` in case root's Java is special

Comment: @Fedricko.. The unix server is using Java1.8.0_251 version.. but when i execute the script manually it works fine.. the same script i had mentioned in crontab